# Space Between stops working when using Expanded or Flexible widget within Row texts to prevent RenderFlex overflow

Tags: flutter

When using the Expanded or Flexible widget to avoid render flex overflow caused by text content within a Row widget, the space between applied to separate the texts is lost.

This is a custom widget that I created to use within the application, here is the code:

```
class CustomInfoRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String value;
  final bool hasDivider;

  const CustomInfoRow({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.value,
    required this.hasDivider,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle =
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0);

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                SharedUtils.translate(context, label),
                style: textStyle,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                SharedUtils.translate(context, value),
                style: textStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (hasDivider) const Divider(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I use Flexible widget, it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBXxH.jpg)

When I use Expanded widget, it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwaYb.jpg)

This is how I want it looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orKVf.jpg)

Please, I appreciate help to solve this situation.

I want to achieve what is described in the last image

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `Flexible` from your Text on the right.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```dart
class CustomInfoRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final String value;
  final bool hasDivider;

  const CustomInfoRow({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.value,
    required this.hasDivider,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle =
        Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0);

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                label,
                style: textStyle,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            Text(
              value,
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (hasDivider) const Divider(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, when addressing the issue raised in the Stack Overflow question regarding the loss of space between texts when using `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets within a `Row`, there are several approaches that can be taken to resolve this layout challenge.

1. **Use `SizedBox` for Explicit Spacing**:
   One straightforward solution is to introduce `SizedBox` widgets between the text elements in the `Row` to create explicit space. `SizedBox` can have a fixed width or be defined by a `widthFactor` to determine its width relative to available space.

   ```dart
   children: [
     Expanded(
       child: Text(
         SharedUtils.translate(context, label),
         style: textStyle,
       ),
     ),
     SizedBox(width: 16.0), // Add an explicit space here
     Expanded(
       child: Text(
         SharedUtils.translate(context, value),
         style: textStyle,
       ),
     ),
   ]
   ```
2. **Utilize `Flexible` with Appropriate `flex` Values**:
   The `Flexible` widget offers more flexibility than `Expanded` as it allows you to specify the flexibility of a child with a `flex` attribute. By adjusting the `flex` value, you can better control how the space is distributed among the children of the `Row`.

   ```dart
   children: [
     Flexible(
       flex: 1,
       child: Text(
         SharedUtils.translate(context, label),
         style: textStyle,
       ),
     ),
     SizedBox(width: 16.0), // Space between texts
     Flexible(
       flex: 1,
       child: Text(
         SharedUtils.translate(context, value),
         style: textStyle,
       ),
     ),
   ]
   ```
3. **Adjust `MainAxisAlignment` for Even Distribution**:
   If you want the space to be evenly distributed not only between the text elements but also from the elements to the edges of the `Row`, you can use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` or `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`. These alignment properties will create equal spaces in the direction of the main axis.

   ```dart
   Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
     children: [
       Expanded(
         child: Text(
           SharedUtils.translate(context, label),
           style: textStyle,
         ),
       ),
       // No need for SizedBox here, as spaceEvenly creates equal spaces
       Expanded(
         child: Text(
           SharedUtils.translate(context, value),
           style: textStyle,
         ),
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```

Remember to adjust the size of the space and the `flex` values according to the specific layout requirements and design intentions. These suggestions should help you address the issue and achieve the desired layout appearance.